# Project Gazelle Tracker give an error

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I have on my Linux Ubuntu 12.04 Server Project Gazelle installed.
I have upload a .iso and would download it, but my Transmission give my this error
 `Tracker gave an error: Tracker gave HTTP response code 404`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fatal error, it's usually alleviated by having multiple trackers for each torrent. In this instance it most likely means that the responding host to a tracker `GET` request isn't serving tracker responses at the path requested. A common request path is something like `/announce`.

You might assume the error is at the server end, and give them some time to resume functionality, ignore the error completely on account of Transmission finding peers through other trackers and means such as DHT, or check for proxies and other HTTP caching on the path to the origin server causing an incorrect response.